# Error( Failed to get SMSC number from phone) in python-gammu when sending sms

Tags: sms, gammu

I got this error in sending sms:
gammu.ERR_GETTING_SMSC: {'Text': u'Failed to get SMSC number from phone.', 'Code': 69, 'Where': 'SendSMS'}

Here is the code I use

```
import gammu

sm = gammu.StateMachine()
sm.ReadConfig()
sm.Init()

message = {
    'Text': 'python-gammu testing message', 
    'SMSC': {'Location': 1},
    'Number': '+###############',
}

sm.SendSMS(message)
```

Comment: Can you share debug log as well? Most likely the SMSC number is not set in the phone/SIM card.

Comment: I guess so since when I try to add the number on SMSC manually it works fine. Could you send a link on how to set SMSC in SIM card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the SMSC is not set on the SIM card. You can verify this using gammu:

```
gammu getsmsc 1
```

To store it on SIM card, you can do:

```
gammu setsmsc 1 "+4208001234567"
```